# Exporting waypoints as .kmz file from Google Earth Pro

Tags: google-earth

I have a series of waypoints on Google Earth Pro (GEP) which I want to export as a .kmz file for import into my UAS software. The UAS software can then use the waypoints to create a flight route for the UAS. I know how to create the waypoints in GEP, but I don't know how to select all the waypoints and export them as a single .kmz file.
[image]

Comment: Google Earth Pro is a desktop application not a web application. I will migrate to [su]